# SharedPreferences in OnPause() access from onCreate if exists- APP CRASHING

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am doing a school project, so specifically, the shared preferences needs to be saved from the OnPause method, then called in the OnCreate method and placed into the value of the editText if it exists in sharedPreferences. The button in activity two "button_dont" should just take you back to activity one, which it does, but now I have added the onPause method it keeps closing the app.

On top of this, I don't understand how to access the ADB from the emulator I am using. I tried finding the file in DeviceManager from android studio but I can't find my project name within the data file. I'm new at this. What can I try next?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        >
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="256dp"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="@string/enterName"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="441dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="127dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="@string/next" />
    </GridLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NameActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="416dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_dont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dont_call"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_do"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/thank_you"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code:

```
public class NameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);

        TextView welcome = findViewById(R.id.welcome);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String name = i.getStringExtra("Value");
        welcome.setText("Welcome "+ name +"!");

        Button button_dont = findViewById(R.id.button_dont);
        Button button_do = findViewById(R.id.button_do);

        button_dont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("result",0);

                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    
            button_do.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("result",1);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button next;
    EditText editText;
    public static final int REQ_CODE=1014;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button next = findViewById(R.id.next);
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NameActivity.class);
                String name = editText.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("Value",name);
                startActivityForResult(i,1014);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Names", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("name", editText.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        int result = data.getIntExtra("result", 2);

        if (result == 1) {
          finish();
        }
    }}
```

Comment: If your app is crashing, look in the Logcat tab in Android studio to find the stack trace. It will give you a lot of helpful information about what is causing the crash (an error message, a line number, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create in onpause and access on oncreate, you can only create outside on create and initialize in oncreate then use in other functions.

For this, u need to initialize the function in oncreate, then u can use else where.
Like this

`````
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button next;
    EditText editText;
    public static final int REQ_CODE=1014;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Names", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("name", editText.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

        Button next = findViewById(R.id.next);
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NameActivity.class);
                String name = editText.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("Value",name);
                startActivityForResult(i,1014);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
       
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        int result = data.getIntExtra("result", 2);

        if (result == 1) {
          finish();
        }
    }}````

So when u do it like this, u can call and use it anywhere in the class
`````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).